# How do I display text in an android application?

Tags: java, android, parsing

I had a project for one of my classes that had us create a bible searching program.  We have an opened ended final part to our project that allows us to do something to improve our project. I want to make it an android app, but i dont really understand the android gui.  I have in the eclipse graphical layout a input field and buttons, but i cant figure out how to link the buttons to methods.  Also, how would I be able to display the results? before I had a Jeditor pane that I used html to parse together tables for each result. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is extremely open ended. Try getting a few sample programs to work, then ask more specific questions once you get stuck.

Comment: I can recommend the official [API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

Comment: +1 I couldn't agree more.  The Android Developer site has a fantastic set of tutorials http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You're going to tie the code to the XML like this ...

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.idOfYourMainLayoutFile);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idOfYourTextViewInXML); 
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idOfYourButtonInXML);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
            @Override
            onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("some bible verse");
                // ... do something when the button is clicked
            }
        });
        // other code in onCreate()
    }
}
```

Comment: okay im gonna have to take some time to study this, but thanks!